# how I can say I am dizzy in korean : 자꾸 어지러워?

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-meaning

I am a beginner in Korean and I just started learning one week ago. I am still in A1 and I want to say this in korean:

**I am dizzy**

I found this way:   **자꾸 어지러워**

and its pronunciation is :  jakku eojileowo

y question is : it is the correct way of saying this for everybody, for example, for older,younger, family member,etc, or do there exist different ways for every person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, he is bothering me for money frequently. 요즘 자주 용돈을
달라고 한다.

Today, he is bothering me for money repeatedly. 오늘따라, 자꾸
용돈을 달라고 한다.

@자주 is used to describe the character and 자꾸 is used to describe
out of general pattern.

Answer (score 5):

The word for dizzy in Korean is 어지럽다.
You don't need to use 자꾸 - this word indicates something that "keeps happening" - I think you would say "자꾸 어지러워" if you were getting dizzy a lot, as in describing a symptom or a problem you've had lately.
So you just need the word "어지럽다" to say "I am dizzy (now)", but you should change the ending:

- 어지러워요 is a polite ending, and it's the safest form for beginners.
- 어지러워 is a casual form that you'll here between friends and to younger people, but you need to be careful using it at first.
- 어지럽습니다 is a very polite / formal form.

Comment: thank you  I said this: 자꾸 어지러워 in a song from kpop and I think is correct because a group kpop girl said this because they are people korean, do you think?

Comment: It is correct - but it means more like "I keep getting dizzy"  If you just want to say you are dizzy right now, it's enough to say just "어지러위(요)".